# Check source contain replace string

Tags: c#

I created this function  it is looking for the html tag  and replacing it with the ^value. It seems complicated wanted to know if there is a better way to do something like this.

> Will you review the syntax, structure, and logic of my code. It can be tested using the main.

Output

```
dsfsadfsad 5<sup>8</sup> dsfsadfsad
dsfsadfsad 5^8  dsfsadfsad
```

Code

```
namespace Replacestring
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string source = "dsfsadfsad 5<sup>8</sup> dsfsadfsad";
            Console.WriteLine(source);
            source = superscriptRule(source);
            Console.WriteLine(source);

        }

        protected static string superscriptRule(string source)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) == true)
            {
                if (source.Contains("<sup>"))
                {
                    Match m = Regex.Match(source, @"<sup>\s*(.+?)\s*</sup>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    if (m.Success)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        string x = m.Groups[1].Value;
                        bool result = int.TryParse(x, out i);
                        if (result == true)
                        {
                            string replacestring = string.Format("<sup>{0}</sup>", x);
                            string newstring = string.Format("^{0} ", x);
                            source = source.Replace(replacestring, newstring);
                            return source;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                    }
                    return source;
                }

            }
            return source;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't a simple `return source.Replace("<sup>", "^").Replace("<\sup>", string.Empty);` be enough?

Comment: @Jefferson, also, you can compare to using String.Split(), might be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Method names should be named using `PascalCase` casing.
- An `if` condition is just a boolean expression hence `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) == true)` is a little bit over the top. Either write

  ```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
  {

  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) { return source; }
  ```

  which saves one level of indentation.
- Why is the method `protected` ? Doesn't make sense to me.
- The name of that method sounds rather like a class/object name than a method name. Methodnames should contain a verb or verb-phrase.

Instead of the `Regex` stuff and `string.Contains()` etc your method could just look like so

```
private static string SuperscriptRule(string source)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) { return source; }

    return source.Replace("<sup>", "^").Replace("<\sup>", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: it could be also simplified to `return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) ? source.Replace("<sup>", "^").Replace("<\sup>", string.Empty) : source;`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few major issues here. First, as already noted you could use `if (x) {...}` instead of `if (x == true) {...}`. Second the variable `result` is only used once so you can move the entire `int.TryParse(x, out i)` into the if condition: `if (int.TryParse(x, out i)) {...}`. Next you type `return source;` four times but you only need it once: at the end of the method. And fourth the first two conditions can be combined as C# uses shortcircuiting in evaluating if conditions. So `if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(source) || source.Contains("<sup>")) {...}`.

Also I'm not too familiar with regexes in C# but I suspect you can skip the `source.Contains("<sup>")` command entirely as the regex call makes it redundant. And I suspect the `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)` can be replaced with `source != null` for the same reason.

Also in the words of JetBrains: Invert 'if' statement to reduce nesting. That is instead of:

```
if (cond1) {
    doStuff();
    if (cond2) {
        doMoreStuff();
    }
}
return;
```

You have:

```
if (!cond1) {
    return;
}
doStuff();
if (cond2) {
    doMoreStuff();
}
return;
```

If you have nested if conditions it's probably a good idea. But it's pretty minor (some people may even disagree on this one).